# Does anybody know how to get a previous and next image with low opacity in a jQuery Slider?

Tags: jquery, slider

I want to archive something like this: http://www.jayhollywood.com.au/ but instead of small previous and next images, I would like them to remain the same size but with low opacity.

(Will this work in IE too?)

Comment: +1 for "will it work in IE too?" lol

Answer (score 1):

It appears that site is using [jQuery Infinite Carousel](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/). Instead of top and bottom borders, you could just overlay a div with reduced opacity on the sides.